# Writing an App with jQuery - how to store variables?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, save, reset

I guess it's somewhere on the web, but I just cannot find it..

So here's my problem:

I am writing an app with jQuery and PhoneGap and I have the problem that when I use window.location.href in my script-tags my global variables are resetted. I tried to store them in HTML LocalStorage, but it even resets them.

My JavaScript file which is bound in any file looks something like this:

```
var x;
var y;
var z;
...
function ...
   x = 5;
function ...
   alert(x);
```

I have an extra .html file for every new page. When I navigate with  my global variables ain't resetted.. But I want a conditional href and for that I think I need the window.location.href in JavaScript.

So anyone can tell me a way to either avoid my variables getting resetted by window.location.href, or how to implement a conditional href that doesn't reset my global variables?

I am having trouble with this for days now, again I am sorry if it is somewhere on the web.

Thanks!!

Comment: try using cookies to store variables

Answer (score 1):

You are reloading the JavaScript, resetting the variables. Some solutions:

- You should use ajax to change your content.
- Use cookies. (Not recommended)
- Store the variables as parameters in the url. (Not pretty)

Comment: Does this works for most browsers? Especially for Android and iOS? I will try this now, since sessionStorage doesn't work. .(

Comment: AJAX works in all browsers I know. JQuery ajax is as easy as: `$('#target').load(src);`

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using sessionStorage to store and restore your variable values across different pages. If that fails, use cookies. But, since you seem to be targeting smartphones, it shouldn't be a problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried something out, the thing is window.location.href loads this html file and doesn't link to it. Thus I really need the JavaScript file in the header otherwise it won't use it. But when I have it, it initializes all variables fresh, thus it won't work with the old ones..

Comment: The problem is that you're loading a new page. The javascript from the original page does not exist there . You either need to add javascript to the second page, or don't load a new page. Use AJAX instead to dynamically load information from the second page and display it on the first.

Comment: Yes, that's actually the problem. :/
Well I am trying to get into AJAX. But I only find unconditional hrefs..

Comment: Do I have to put all pages in one html file to href with AJAX?

Comment: I would suggest you look up some tutorials on AJAX using jQuery. It's pretty simple. Here is a quick example of loading html from a page and putting it into some div:

`$.ajax({
  url:"pagetwo.html",
  cache:false,
  success:function(content){
    $("#somedivid").html(content);
  }
});`